# Java creating a file in a certain directory

Tags: java, json, directory, filepath

How do I get a json file I am creating to go into another directory. I am using a method that gives a file name and use this code to create it, its not the full code but Im pretty sure this is the only part I need to modify.

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName);
     JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(in));
```

right now it puts it in a directory but I want to put it in a folder in that directory.

this also does not work

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/A/Ab/src/serv"+fileName);
```

///////////////////////////

```
File cDir = new File("");
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(cDir.getAbsoluteFile() +fileName);
```

Comment: If all that(in variations i believe you tried desperately) doesn't help:  Can you provide something, for us to reproduce the behavior? At the moment I am staring at your lines, that give me no problems when trying. Somehow we are overlooking something. Maybe 'cause its also missing in your question or 'cause we are not seeing it.

Comment: Your code contains `"/A/Ab/src/serv" + fileName` - note that have not included a `/` between the directory and the file name. Could that be your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
File dir = new File("/A/Ab/src/serv");
if (!dir.exists()) dir.mkdirs();
```

then:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/A/Ab/src/serv/" + filename);`enter code here`
```

If the directory already exists and you just want to create a new file, then simply do:

```
 FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("/A/Ab/src/serv/" + filename))
```

Comment: I tried this code still nothing the thing is I dont want to create a new directory I want to put it in one of the ones I Have

Comment: If the directory already exists, then simply do:FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("/A/Ab/src/serv/" + filename))

Comment: that didtnt work either im so confused about why it keeps going to the same place